# Java GC Overhead Limit Error Using JUnit 5 TestFactory With large stream of dynamicTest (DynamicContainer / DynamicNode)

Tags: junit, java-8, java-stream, maven-surefire-plugin, junit5

I am facing the below issue when trying to create and run a large number of JUnit 5 dynamic tests using maven-surefire-plugin 2.21.0

> [ERROR] GC overhead limit exceeded
>   [ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process
>   [ERROR] GC overhead limit exceeded
>   [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:673)
>   [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:535)
>   [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:280)
>   [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:245)
>   [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1124)
>   [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:954)
>   [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:832)
>   [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
>   [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
>   [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
>   [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
>   [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
>   [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
>   [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
>   [ERROR]     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)

and below is my code, it is a db comparison tool. What basically I am doing is, stream data from two databases and compare the record and fail a test if there is a difference in any of two records so there will be as many dynamic tests created as many records in the db (~14M), pretty large, not sure whether dynamic tests were meant to use at this scale. Any help on this regard is greatly appreciated :)

```
 @TestFactory
Stream<DynamicNode> dynamicTestsWithContainers() throws SQLException {
    return tableNameProvider()//List of db tables ~100
            .map(tableName -> dynamicContainer(tableName, dynamicNodeStream(tableName)));
}

private Stream<DynamicNode> dynamicNodeStream(String tableName) {

    try {
        System.out.println("Testing " + tableName);
        Stream<Row> rows = sourceRepo.rows(tableName);
        Stream<List<Row>> batchRows = batch(rows, 10000);
        Optional<TableSchema> tableInfo = sourceRepo.getTableSchema(tableName);


        final Stream<DynamicNode> dynamicNodeStream = batchRows
                .flatMap(batch -> {

                    Map<String, Row> sourceRowsMap = buildRowMap(batch, tableInfo.get());//HashMap with 10000 Objects
                    Map<String, Row> targetRowsMap = targetRepo.getTargetDBRows(sourceRowsMap, tableInfo.get());//HashMap with 10000 Objects
                    Set<String> commonKeys = Sets.intersection(sourceRowsMap.keySet(), targetRowsMap.keySet());

                    final Stream<DynamicTest> dynamicTestStream = Streams.concat(
                            Stream.of(
                                    dynamicTest("All source records should be present in target DB", () -> assertThat(targetRowsMap.keySet())
                                            .as("Comparing " + sourceRepo.getServerName() + " against " + targetRepo.getServerName())
                                            .hasSameElementsAs(sourceRowsMap.keySet()))
                            ),
                            commonKeys
                                    .stream()
                                    .map(rowKey -> dynamicTest(tableName + " Row with #" + rowKey + " should be same in target DB",
                                            () -> assertThat(targetRowsMap.get(rowKey).getRowData())
                                                    .isEqualToComparingFieldByFieldRecursively(sourceRowsMap.get(rowKey).getRowData())
                                    ))

                    );

                    return dynamicTestStream;
                });

        return dynamicNodeStream;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error running tests on table " + tableName, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of "scale" are we talking about here? In other words, how many dynamic tests is your factory generating?

Comment: ~14 Million Test, I am trying to write a DB comparison tool and for comparison of each row I create a dynamic test.

Comment: Can you run the tests without maven/surefire involved? Just the console launcher, maybe?

Comment: running from console launcher also results in same error.

Comment: Even though this is two years later, you might be interested in the progress: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1445

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC</argLine>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

in your build profile to allow concurrent garbage collection.